# How to generate ERC-20/xxx token addresses?

Tags: go-ethereum, addresses, web3j, address.transfer

How to generate ERC-20/xxx token addresses, from which I can receive/send corresponding tokens? How can I do this using web3j?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal Ethereum addresses work for all ERC-20, ERC-721, and other Ethereum Based Tokens.

These tokens actually live as a part of a token contract, for example look at the Basic Attention Token (BAT) contract:

https://etherscan.io/address/0x0d8775f648430679a709e98d2b0cb6250d2887ef#code

This means that interacting with these tokens (sending, getting balance of, etc...) is as simple as calling the corresponding functions in this contract.

Maybe start here: [Send Custom ERC20 Tokens from one Address to another](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/issues/213)